# deja-dup wrong behaviour with google drive

Tags: 20.04, backup, deja-dup, online-accounts, google-drive

I had a google account connected to Ubuntu20.04. I tried to make a backup to google drive and as intended, the backup started normally. I didn't have enough free space in this account so I decided to connect another account to Ubuntu. The problem now is that deja-dup keeps making backups on previous account and I cannot really find a way to change that. I tried
`sudo apt-get purge deja-dup duplicity` and it insists to connect to the previous account that it is totally disconnected from Ubuntu 20.04LTS.
Is there anything that I miss or is it something like a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just noticed I was having this issue myself. After much trial and error, I've found that deja-dup isn't using information from the google accounts you have connected to ubuntu. Instead it's set up itself as a connected app directly on your google drive.

If you open google drive on the account you no longer wish to back up to, and go to settings -> manage apps, you can disconnect deja-dup from the account there. Then when you next back up it should prompt you to connect to a google account, and you can do this with the second account instead.